# how to use a loop in gnuplot and skipping a column?

Tags: gnuplot

I have file called 'X.txt' which is like this:

```
0.24 -0.483 -0.482 0.0 1999.6 1133.2 0.0 1716.4 802.08 0.0 ..... (continues to 600 columns)
```

I want to plot this file in a loop but skipping one column, like this:

plot 'X.txt' u **2:3** w l,'X.txt' u **5:6** w l,'X.txt' u **8:9** w l, ....

You can see after **2:3** I have to skip 4 or after **8:9** I have to skip 10 and so on up to **209:210**. I used this command line but it doesn't work:

plot for [i=2:209 :2] for [j=3:210 :2] 'X1' u i:j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a single iteration variable:

```
plot for [i=2:209:3] 'X1' u i:(column(i+1))
```

(I cannot test at the moment if `using i:i+1` also works)

Comment: But this cannot skip one column.

Comment: It does, have you tried it? In the first iteration i=2 and you plot 2:3, the next iteration sets i=5 ( increment is 3) and you plot 5:6, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot for [i=2:210:3] 'X1.txt' using i:i+1
```

That should do the trick

first iteration : i=2 using 2:3

second iteration : i=5 using 5:6

(4 was skipped)

And so on

Comment: Glad to help ;)